# Editing the hosts file on the Android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hosts

I changed the hosts file on the Android Studio emulator and wrote me the address of the web pages, but it still does not open. What is the problem? On my PC with the modified host file everything works.

[pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys34g.png)

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blicV.png)

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC0D2.png)

Comment: can you try to use IP address instead of Host name?

Comment: unfortunately not, when specifying only the ip page does not load

Comment: when specifying only the ip page does not load this is likely the problem. It won't load with hosts as well, as mapping domain to IP works same way as if you were quering the IP instead of domain

Answer (score 0):

One possible is that the hosts file must be in UNIX format, not DOS.  Another issue is that the emulator defines a gateway router between the emulated device and the host PC.  The gateway is at 10.0.2.2.  If you intend to talk to a web server on the host, use that IP address.